# Json Parse C# and convert to key and value

Tags: c#, json

I have a C# program and I have a **JSON** data `{"emp_id": 3676}`, I want make a `List<keyvalue<string,string>>`, so I want to add *"emp_id"* as a key and *3637* as a value.

Comment: What is `keyvalue`? Do you mean `KeyValuePair`? What have you tried so far? Can you give a more complete example of your JSON, showing multiple pairs rather than just a single one?

Comment: why `List<keyvalue<string,string>>`, That you can have a `Dictionary<string, string>`?

Comment: I have this json data   ----  {[
  {
   "emp_id": 3675,
    "emp_name": Mr. Adam,
    
  },
  {
    "emp_id": 3676,
    "emp_name": Mr. Dams,
    
  },
  {
    "emp_id": 3677,
    "emp_name": Ms. Dia,
    
  }
]}   ---------- I want to save it to List<List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>>

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the excellent library [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)
It has a method for this `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Category>>` that would do all the hard work for you

Comment: I have this json data ---- {[ { "emp_id": 3675, "emp_name": Mr. Adam, }, { "emp_id": 3676, "emp_name": Mr. Dams, }, { "emp_id": 3677, "emp_name": Ms. Dia, } ]} ---------- I want to save it to List<List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>>